# Converting string to integer with float error

Tags: python, list, csv

I'm trying to import a CSV on Python 3 then append it and float it so I can then use it to do some calculations.

```
import csv
data=[]
file=input ("Enter file name: ")
with open(file,"r") as f:
    reader=csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        data.append(row) #creating list of lists
print (data)

print("Calculate COV")
lst = [val for subl in data for val in subl] #converting to list
float(lst) #error
print (lst)

def list_var(lst):
    var = 0
    avg = sum(lst)/len(lst)
    for i in lst:
        var += (avg - i)**2
    return
SD=list_var(lst)
print (SD)
```

This is what I get:

```
 TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

Comment: what does your `lst` look like?

Comment: Why would you convert a string to an integer with `float`? You mean *"converting string to float with `float`"*, surely?

Comment: This is the non-appended list: [['13.25', '12.97', '13.12', '13.47', '13.44', '13.09', '12.86', '12.78', '12.91', '12.93', '12.91', '13.11'], ['12.92', '13.42', '13.58', '13.7', '13.62', '13.7', '13.31', '12.86', '12.59', '12.81', '13.46', '12.9'], ['13.39', '13.5', '13.29', '13.26', '13.38', '13.45', '13.46', '11.95', '', '12.57', '13.22', '12.88'], ['12.48', '13.76', '13.7', '13.77', '13.08', '13.48', '13.25', '12.31', '12.56', '12.56', '12.95', '13.38'], ['12.52', '14.07', '14.46', '14.13', '13.98', '14.07', '13.92', '12.7', '13.01', '12.79', '13', '13.13']]

Comment: I'm trying to convet the string to integers so i can use them in functions

Comment: @Tetra again, I think you mean *"to floats"* - integers are a different type of number - see [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#numbers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
flattened = [float(x) for y in data for x in y if x]
print flattened
[13.25, 12.97, 13.12, 13.47, 13.44, 13.09, 12.86, 12.78, 12.91, 12.93, 12.91, 13.11, 12.92, 13.42, 13.58, 13.7, 13.62, 13.7, 13.31, 12.86, 12.59, 12.81, 13.46, 12.9, 13.39, 13.5, 13.29, 13.26, 13.38, 13.45, 13.46, 11.95, 12.57, 13.22, 12.88, 12.48, 13.76, 13.7, 13.77, 13.08, 13.48, 13.25, 12.31, 12.56, 12.56, 12.95, 13.38, 12.52, 14.07, 14.46, 14.13, 13.98, 14.07, 13.92, 12.7, 13.01, 12.79, 13.0, 13.13]
```

If you want to clean your output do it before you append to data.

```
with open(file,"r") as f:
    reader=csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        data.append(row)
```

Put a `print row` in your loop to see exactly what your data looks like, then remove whatever you need to make it valid to cast as a float.

Wherever you data looks like :

```
lst= [['1;2;3;4;5'], ['65;5;64;65;2'], ['215;5;85;65;54']]

spl= [x.split(";") for y in lst for x in y]
flattened = [float(x) for y in spl for x in y if x]
print flattened
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 65.0, 5.0, 64.0, 65.0, 2.0, 215.0, 5.0, 85.0, 65.0, 54.0]
```

Comment: Do you mean "for y in data for x"?

Comment: @Tetra, yes, whichever is your list of lists you posted, you have `""` in there so using `if x` won't try to convert it to a float.

Comment: I still get:  "ValueError: could not convert string to float: "

Comment: is your list as you posted in the comments and  what is the error exactly?

Comment: No I'm now using a simple one:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Marc\Desktop\Python\Metal Loss\other.py", line 11, in <module>
    lst = [float(x) for y in data for x in y if x]
  File "C:\Users\Marc\Desktop\Python\Metal Loss\other.py", line 11, in <listcomp>
    lst = [float(x) for y in data for x in y if x]
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1;2;3;4;5'

Comment: @Tetra split and convert them to float

Comment: how has your output changed?

Comment: The output is the same

Comment: @Tetra, how do you have `;` in your list if they were not there before?

Comment: just remove that before you append to you data and you will be fine. What does a row look like?

Comment: @Tetra, I added to my answer using your before data.

Answer (score 4):

your trying to convert `list to float` . try

```
lst = [float(val) for subl in data for val in subl if val.strip()]
```

i think your list comprehension should look like this

```
lst= [[float(val) for val in subl if val.strip()] for subl in data ]
```

if your list look like below and your flatterning the list try below code

```
lst=[['13.25', '12.97', '13.12', '13.47', '13.44', '13.09', '12.86', '12.78', '12.91', '12.93', '12.91', '13.11'],
     ['12.92', '13.42', '13.58', '13.7', '13.62', '13.7', '13.31', '12.86', '12.59', '12.81', '13.46', '12.9'],
     ['13.39', '13.5', '13.29', '13.26', '13.38', '13.45', '13.46', '11.95', '', '12.57', '13.22', '12.88'], 
     ['12.48', '13.76', '13.7', '13.77', '13.08', '13.48', '13.25', '12.31', '12.56', '12.56', '12.95', '13.38'], 
     ['12.52', '14.07', '14.46', '14.13', '13.98', '14.07', '13.92', '12.7', '13.01', '12.79', '13', '13.13']]
```

then try

```
from itertools import chain
newlst=[ float(val) for val in chain.from_iterable(lst) if val.strip()]
```

this method is not good coding practice but helps

```
newlst=[]
for val in chain.from_iterable(lst):#
    if val.strip():
        try:
            newlst.append(float(val))
        except ValueError:
            # here you print the val . 
            #and check what type of val is coming here and perform logic 
            #so that you can convert these type also into float
            for i in val.split(';'):
                newlst.append(float(i if i.strip() else 0))

            pass
```

whitout itertools

```
for subl in data:
    for val in subl:
        if val.strip():
            try:
                newlst.append(float(val))
            except ValueError:
                # here you print the val . 
                #and check what type of val is coming here and perform logic 
                #so that you can convert these type also into float
                for i in val.split(';'):
                    newlst.append(float(i if i.strip() else 0))

                pass
```

Comment: Is it possible without using itertools?

Comment: @Tetra you don't need a try/except block clean your output when you are getting the data from the file.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham First, how do i clean the data? Second, I now get the error in the first function:                        Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Marc\Desktop\Python\Metal Loss\other.py", line 22, in <module>
    SD=list_var(results)
  File "C:\Users\Marc\Desktop\Python\Metal Loss\other.py", line 18, in list_var
    avg = sum(results)/len(results)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1;2;3;4;5'

Comment: @Tetra add what row looks like to your question

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham a row is shown by "[]" before appending

Comment: Before: [['1;2;3;4;5'], ['65;5;64;65;2'], ['215;5;85;65;54']]                                               after: ['1;2;3;4;5', '65;5;64;65;2', '215;5;85;65;54']

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham using a simple example now